# Translate design:attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, design, attribute

Is it possible to use custom label when using the `<design:attribute>` tag?

I can merge in labels like `label="{!$Label.myNamespace.my_Label}"` in a component but does it not render when using `design:attribute`.

Comment: Sorry, this is currently not supported https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm

Answer (score 2):

Below is an experimental approach

1.Create a Custom Label Named Hello

[image]

2.Create a component named **HelloworldTranslate.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
 <aura:attribute name="subject" type="String" />
 <aura:attribute name="greeting" type="String"/>
 <p>{!v.subject}</p>
 <p>{!v.greeting}</p>
</aura:component>
```

3.Create a Design File like below .

```
<design:component label="Hello World">
 <design:attribute name="subject" label="Subject" description="Name of the person you want to greet" default="{!$Label.SEDreamin.Hello}"/>
 <design:attribute name="greeting" label="Greeting" />
```

> The Key here is observe how i have include label as merge syntax **{!$Label.SEDreamin.Hello}**

where Hello is the label name and SEDreamin is org namespace .For org with no namespace use "c"

4.Translate the label .I used French here

5.Drag the component on the Home page 
[image]

6.Choose a User with other language and login in back .You should see translated label

[image]

One thing i observed the app caches so clear the cache and log in back to confirm translation

> Another caveat I observed is it does not seem to work for community builder

Comment: What is "SEDreamin"?

Comment: Namespace of the org

Comment: Replace with c for normal org without namespace

Comment: Still seem to be struggling getting this to work with community builder - anybody else seeing this?